# How to create multiselect dropdown on bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm coding js app that parse some data and show it to users in table that generated by js. So i need to give to user dropdown list or something like that to choose fields that will be used to generate this table.
Are there any simple way to make this? I've only found 
http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/
https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/examples/

But it's just dropdown select list! why i have to include jquery and thousand another scripts?

So, tell me pls simplest way to create multiselect tool. I cant imagine, that simpliest way - ugly checkbox :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

selfanswere.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="bla"><label for="bla">
```

css - checbox visible false

Answer (score 0):

The basic one:

```
<select multiple>
    <option>Option 1</option>
    <option>Option 2</option>
    <option>Option 3</option>
</select>
```

Hold ctrl to select multiple